# conventions in signals naming in datasheets

Tags: embedded, memory, flash

What does it mean when the datasheets lists the signals between parentheses as shown in the figure below?
[image]

Comment: This needs context - what is the device?

Comment: 28F640J3 Parallel flash memory

Comment: Can you add a link to the datasheet (and a reference to the page number) in the original question?

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the datasheet a write operation can be initiated (and terminated) with either CEx or WE#, whichever goes low last, thus you can have the two waveform alternatively; if the upper of the two waveform is CEx the lower il WE#, else you should read the upper as WE# and the lower as CEx.

In the [datasheet](http://www-mtl.mit.edu/Courses/6.111/labkit/datasheets/28F128J3A.pdf), the notes from table 17 should be enlightening.